# BadPadding Exception using same cipher instance

Tags: java, encryption

I have this encryption code which works no problem. I can decrypt the text it encrypts in another language, but I need to decrypt it in java now.

```
 private static final String AES = "AES";
    private static final String CBC_BLOCK = "CBC";
    private static final String ECB_BLOCK = "ECB";
    private static final String PADDING = "PKCS5Padding";
    private static final String AES_CBC_PCKS5_CIPHER_CONFIG = AES + "/" + CBC_BLOCK + "/" + PADDING;
    private static final String AES_ECB_PCKS5_CIPHER_CONFIG = AES + "/" + ECB_BLOCK + "/" + PADDING;

 public static String encryptInAesEcbPkcs5Padding(String salt, String message) {
        String encryptedMessage = "";
        SecretKeySpec key = null;
        try {
            if (message != null && !message.equals("")) {
                key = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), AES);
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ECB_PCKS5_CIPHER_CONFIG);
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
                encryptedMessage = convertMessageToBase64(cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "No such algorithm [" + AES + "]", e);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "No such padding for algorithm [" + AES + "]", e);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "Invalid block size for [" + AES + "/" + ECB_BLOCK + "]", e);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "Invalid padding [" + PADDING + "]", e);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Invalid key [" + key + "]", e);
        }
        return encryptedMessage;
    }
```

Trying to decrypt with this code. I am using the exact same salt as the encryption and passing in the string the encrypter creates as the "message"

```
  public static String decrypt(String message, String salt) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
            SecretKeySpec key = null;
            String string = null;
            try {
                if (message != null && !message.equals("")) {
  String decoded = convertBase64ToMessage(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    key = new SecretKeySpec(salt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), AES);
                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ECB_PCKS5_CIPHER_CONFIG);
                    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
                    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(decoded.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    string = new String(decrypted);
                }
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "No such algorithm [" + AES + "]", e);
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "No such padding for algorithm [" + AES + "]", e);
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
                LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "Invalid block size for [" + AES + "/" + ECB_BLOCK + "]", e);
            } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
                LOGGER.error(LogPreFix.ERROR + "Invalid padding [" + PADDING + "]", e);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Invalid key [" + key + "]", e);
            }
            return string;
        }
```

But I get this error, since i am using the same Cipher instance as i did when encrypting it, I am not sure why I cannot decrypt the message.

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`convertBase64ToMessage` should not return a `String`, but rather a `byte[]`, because ciphertexts cannot be represented by a printable string (with a high probability).